Smooth approximation of~$L^p$ functions
EDIT:
Let $u\in L^p (B_r)$ for some ball $B_r\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $1<p<\infty$. I need to find a smooth approximation of $u$, let's call it $u_\sigma$, where $0<\sigma <1$, such that:
$$u_\sigma \to u \qquad \text{in}\;\; L^p(B_r) $$
as well as
$$\|\partial_{x_i} u_\sigma\|_{L^1(\Omega)} \leq C$$
for any $i=1,2,...,n$, with a constant $C$ that is independent of the parameter $\sigma\in(0,1)$. Does such a sequence even exist? My first thought was to use standard mollification with some smooth kernel, but since I require the derivative of the approximation to approximate my function $u$, I am unsure whether this is really the right way. Unfortunately, I cannot think of any other appropriate approximation either! Thanks in advance for any help!
